Thunderbird does not update imap folders anymore take 2
I came to this site, because the issue I am having is exactly the same as the issue posted in this thread that was apparently never resolved. There is a comment that claims the issue was resolved in Thunderbird 115.1.0, but I am having the same issue in Thunderbird 115.10.2 (64 bit) and it just started yesterday.
My IMAP folder structure is not updating.This started yesterday. I created a subfolder as usual in Thunderbird, the folder was not created. I attempted this several times to no avail. I logged into my webmail client and the folder did not exist on the IMAP server. I then created the subfolder in the webmail client and it did appear. I even dropped one of two emails for that subfolder into it so see if that might spur something in Thunderbird to update. I then went back to Thunderbird and tried to get the IMAP folder structure to rebuild by collapsing the folder for that account and expand it again. This usually works to get the new folder to appear. However, it did not work. I have shutdown Thunderbird and restarted it to no avail. I cleared cache and that did nothing as well. I have also restarted Windows, but to no avail.
To make matters worse, I have Thunderbird installed on my Linux box and my Windows laptop which is what I use for work. I am getting the same result from both versions of Thunderbird. There is one difference. The Linux version of Thunderbird receives new mail in the inbox for this account, but the Windows version just hangs on "Connected to mail.mydomain.net" It does not go past this point, so no new mail is downloaded to the Windows version of Thunderbird but it is to the Linux version.
Some solutions that have been posted online are very outdated from 12 to 9 years ago. Any help on where to go would be much appreciated.

Given it is imap, have you actually subscribed to the folder? right-click the account, subscribe, then check it and click subscribe?

I tried that. The problem is, when I click on "Subscribe", the window that is supposed to show the folders to subscribe to is empty. I have done that in the past and it has worked. When I click on "Refresh", nothing happens.

Interestingly, when I tried this on my Linux computer, the folders to subscribe to are listed. All of them that were being automatically subscribed to as the folder were created were listed. But the one I created from the webmail client was not. I checked the box, and it was then listed in the folder tree as it should have been. It appears something is different between the two versions. But the Windows version is the one that is not working now.

For the windows version, I suspect the database is corrupt, and should be repaired.

I have rebuilt the database based on these instructions. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/rebuilding-global-database
That did not work. This is amazing.

This solution I came up with only works if the user has a 2nd version of the same profile running on a different computer. I ended up opening the version of the same profile on my Linux box and exporting the profile. I then went into the profile directory ..\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\ and placed the backup profile zip there. I unzipped the profile folder. I then rename the current profile folder adding .bk to the end of it, just in case I might need it again.I then renamed the backup profile folder what the current profile folder was named. I opened Thunderbird and it works as it did prior to the issue that arose yesterday. All of the email that was not downloading before, including the newly created folders, downloaded and worked just fine.
I cannot say how to fix the original problem if the user does not have a second running version of Thunderbird with the same profile. But for those that do, I hope this helps.

So your profile itself was corrupt. If you had just renamed the profile folder, then started thunderbird, you would get an empty profile. Setup the account(s) and let it download everything again, and you'd have the same result.
